# Overview all sites with contribute permissions

Tags: permissions, web-services, contribute

I have a challenge. On our SharePoint environment, we want to have one page, with all sites where the current user has contribute permissions on. This way, he knows where he can collaborate.

I already found a kind of way to do it with web services on following site http://sympmarc.com/2010/01/29/determining-if-a-user-is-in-a-permission-group-with-sharepoints-web-services/ but I should find a way to do this for all sites in my site collection/farm.

What should be the best approach to do this you guys think?

**UPDATE:** based on the comments I want to let you know it's an on-premise environment. And it should be great to have a solution that shows all sites of all site collections in the web application. Even it's on-premise, a webservice/spservices solution instead of c# would be great :)

Thanks!

Comment: There is this article - [Getting a list of sites that a user has access to in SharePoint](https://johnmhester.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/getting-a-list-of-sites-that-a-user-has-access-to-in-sharepoint/) - which uses Search Results web part to display all sites where user has access. Probably can be a starting point.

Comment: please mention the version if sharepoint and if farm solution is allowed!

Comment: also you want all the sites in the site collection or only the ones below the site on which page exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the permissions of a user using the 'DoesUserHavePermissions' method. See code sample below.

However in order to return all the sites you need to loop over all the sites and site collections. *This is very resource intensive*! I would not recommend it on a webpage or when the code will execute a lot. On a webpage you risk getting slow page responses and time-outs.

In a timerjob that runs only a few times a week or in a one-off script I might consider it.

Personally, I would look into a search solution and some form of (custom) caching.

- Create a content type with the needed info (user, permission).
- For each site, let a timerjob update a (hidden) list with items based on this content type
- Use search to get the information. (Filter on contenttypeid and user)

This is sort of a workaround. Not realtime, but it will be faster than looping over all sites. And more importantly will use a lot less resources.

Make sure you configure the scheduling of the timerjob and the search crawl job correctly.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {                  
        SPBasePermissions permissionToCheck = SPBasePermissions.ManageLists;

        string login = web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
        if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(login, permissionToCheck))
        {
            //user has permissions.
        }       
    }
}
```